# Successively multiply a data frame's previous value by a percentage

Tags: r, tidyverse

I would like to decay the value in a column of a data frame by 2%.  I've tried the below, but vectorization results in all duplicate values.  How can I get iterative decay?

```r
df <-
  data.frame(
    date = c("2023-01-01","2023-01-02","2023-01-03",
             "2023-01-04","2023-01-05","2023-01-06","2023-01-07",
             "2023-01-08","2023-01-09","2023-01-10"),
    value = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
  )

df |>
  tidyr::fill(value) |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    decayed = value * 0.98
  )
#>          date value decayed
#> 1  2023-01-01     1    0.98
#> 2  2023-01-02     1    0.98
#> 3  2023-01-03     1    0.98
#> 4  2023-01-04     1    0.98
#> 5  2023-01-05     1    0.98
#> 6  2023-01-06     1    0.98
#> 7  2023-01-07     1    0.98
#> 8  2023-01-08     1    0.98
#> 9  2023-01-09     1    0.98
#> 10 2023-01-10     1    0.98
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `decayed = cumprod(rep(0.98, n())` - `cumprod` does a cumulative product.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you very much.  But suppose I want the decay rate to be different from the starting value.  For example, the starting value is 150 and the decay rate is 2%.

Comment: In that case you can multiply: `decayed = 150 * cumprod(rep(0.98, n())`